Algorithms textbooks/lecture notes for the blind
Algorithms textbooks and lecture notes are largely inaccessible to the blind. If you can get them in pdf format, today's readers do a terrible job of reading math and make no effort to explain diagrams.
Are there are textbooks or lecture notes that are available in plain text so that a reader can read them correctly?
There are two main obstacles:

Getting hold of LaTeX source of a standard textbook
Finding a tool that can read math in an intelligible way.

The third problem is getting written descriptions of any diagrams.
If one could get hold of the pdf of a standard textbook then the problem would be to find a reader that could read that intelligibly, complete with the math contained.

I'm trying to comprehend a math textbook (yes, including algorithms) that doesn't use, well, math. I do not doubt it is a problem, but the answer is not in finding a non-math algorithms book. https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/112airt/braille_readers/ has some good pointers.

@JonCuster I am not looking for a math free textbook. I am looking for a textbook which is available in plain text and not just pdf.

In the US, a student would have access to an office whose job it is to help with this sort of thing. Is that available to whatever blind person needs this?

@AzorAhai-him- Not really. I mean there is an office but I don't think they provide this sort of help as they know nothing about math and nothing about algorithms.

@Simd - OK, I guess to me when someone says 'plain text' that pretty much rules out all but the very simplest math expressions. I don't consider a integral sign to be plain text. The link did point to devices that can handle docx equations, and I did not read further to see if LeTeX could be handled by something.

Go to that office. They may not know math, but they DO know how to get resources from publishers. Moreover, explaining diagrams and math formulae is a very difficult problem. It needs a solution of course.

@JonCuster One problem, even if that is solved, is how to get hold of LaTeX for a standard algorithms textbook.

The MAA has advice on this (PDF): https://maa.org/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/CUPM-Guide_Resources-for-Teaching-Blind-or-Visually-Impaired-Students.pdf

And this announcement from ~4 years ago may have progressed: https://aimath.org/aimnews/braille/

@Simd You don't think, or you asked them and they said, "Sorry, we can't help, because it's math"?

@AzorAhai-him- I asked  and they didn't have anything useful to say.

Wild suggestion: Some high schools require service hours as part of graduation. See if that office could work with you on seeing if there are any good math students (taking AP classes) at the schools who would be willing to do their service hours helping you. Maybe asynchronous--after training on what you need, recording descriptions of equations and diagrams. The office might have to 'certify' the hours.

And a few questions over on Mathematics Educators: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/search?q=braille

There may be a specialized library which could help? I remember this one: https://katalog.blista.de/ (in Germany), there may be something similar in the country you live in.

This is a summary of recent comments that should be captured. It is flagged as Community Wiki so that people feel free to edit and add resources.
In the US, at least, most colleges and universities will have an Office of Assistance for Accessibility and/or Disability that should be able to help. In particular, they should be able to obtain resources from publishers.
An internet search should turn up some possibilities, though many are for elementary age students.
The MAA has advice on this (PDF).
The AIMath does also.
A search at matheducators turns up some questions and answers.
A redit post  has some pointers.
There is a discussion group for blind mathematicians that may be able to offer advice.
Feel free to add resources.
